# Initiate a subclass object from a string

Tags: java, design-patterns

Consider a multiplayer fighting game, where the client selects a fighter by sending to the server a string that contains the name of the fighter the client just selected.

Consider this "fighters" class structure in the server:

```
Fighter
   Foo extends Fighter
   Bar extends Fighter
   Qux extends Fighter
```

For instance the client sent this `"Bar"` string, how can I initiate a subclass according to this string?

The way I did it is an `enum` like so:

```
public enum Champion {
    Foo {
        @Override
        public Fighter getNew() {
            return new Foo();
        }
    },

    Bar {
        @Override
        public Fighter getNew() {
            return new Bar();
        }
    },

    Qux {
        @Override
        public Fighter getNew() {
            return new Qux();
        }
    };

    public abstract Fighter getNew();

    public static boolean contains(String fighter) {
        for (Champion c : Champion.values()) {
            if (c.name().equals(fighter)) {
                return true;
            }   
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

Then I am getting an object like so:

```
public Fighter getFighter(String fighterName) {
    if(Champion.contains(fighterName)) {
        return Champion.valueOf(fighterName).getNew();
    } else { 
       return null; 
    } // For example sake only :)
}
```

Is this the correct way to deal with this encounter? is there a better way? I remember there is a known pattern to deal with such encounters, but cannot remember exactly which.
If you have an idea please let me know!

Comment: The pattern you are looking for is FactoryMethod

Comment: @sunrise76 but FactoryMethod design pattern doesn't really work well with string as an input, let's say we got over 100 fighters in the game, FactoryMethod design patterns won't scale well, or is it?

Comment: If you don' want lazy creation of objects, create 100+ objects in factory and just use your enum as you are currently using. getFighter is already a factory method.

Answer (score 3):

Using factories, a solution could look like this:

```
interface FighterFactory {
    Fighter create();
}
```

Keep a `Map<String, FighterFactory>` variable in your facade. Each `Fighter` type has to be registered in this map with its Factory.

```
private Map<String, FighterFactory> fighters;

public void register(String name, FighterFactory factory) {
  fighters.put(name, factory);
}
```

In each `Fighter` type embed an inner class `Factory` e.g.

```
class Foo extends Fighter {

  //code for Foo

  public static class Factory implements FighterFactory {
    public Foo create() {
      return new Foo();
    }
  }
}

// and in your Facade

register("Foo", new Foo.Factory());
```

To instantiate a new Fighter do a get to the Fighter-Map and execute create on its result.

```
FighterFactory factory = fighters.get(nameFromClient);
// null handling, if nameFromClient is not a Fighter type;
return factory.create();
```

This design has some advantages over reflection:

- it is secure
- the create method can do more than a constructor

and over the single factory method (one method handles all Fighter types):

- if the create method gets more complex (e.g. more params to create the instance) than your changes to the code are located at the Fighter class and not at the factory method.

and over the enum approach:

- the only feature of Enum that is used is Iterating over its values. Keeping a Map of values replaces the Iterating with a Map lookup
- the information how to construct a Fighter resides located near the Fighter and not in the Champion Enum
- you can even decide that FighterFactories are Top-Level classes, what is not possible with the enum inner class Factories.

Answer (score 1):

If java 8 is an option, you could use a `MapString, Supplier<Fighter>>`:

```
Map<String, Supplier<Fighter>> factories = new HashMap<>();
factories.put("foo", Foo::new);
factories.put("bar", Bar::new);
factories.put("qux", Qux::new);
```

Then, you could get one supplier with a given string, and ask it to create the specialized `Fighter` instance:

```
String s = "bar";
Supplier<Fighter> supplier = factories.get(s);
if (supplier != null) {
    Fighter fighter = supplier.get();
    System.out.println(fighter.getClass().getSimpleName()); // Bar
} else {
    // Handle illegal string
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd start with the simplest thing that works.

```
public Fighter getFighter(String fighterName) {
  if("Foo".equals(fighterName))
     return new Foo();
  if("Bar".equals(fighterName))
     return new Bar();
  ...
  return null;
}
```

Then I'd probably move some logic into the subclasses.

```
public Fighter getFighter(String fighterName) {
 Fighter result = null;
  if((result = Foo.createFromString(fighterName))!=null)
     return result;
  if((result = Bar.createFromString(fighterName))!=null)
     return result;
  ...
  return null;
}
```

There's a lot of directions you can take from here, you can stick construction interfaces into a `Map` or `List`. For example.

```
public registerFighterType(IFighterConstructor constructor) {
  fighterTypes.add(constructor);
}

public Fighter getFighter(String fighterName) {
  for(IFighterConstructor constructor : fighterTypes) {
    Fighter result = constructor.createFromString(fighterName);
    if(result!=null) return result;
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: Does it work better than the `enum` approach I did? it looks like in your example we just loop and construct all possible fighters until we find the one that we need, am I right?

Comment: One advantage to going through the whole list is that you can then allow parameters as part of the string eg. `fighterName = "orc:leader:11hp"` and if the Orc type constructor is smart enough to parse that everything just works... But if you know you're not going to need that kind of flexibility, then you can use a map instead, and you end up with a similar design to CoronA.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
MyClass c = Class.forName("MyClass").newInstance();
```

Looks ugly and might need a cast somewhere in there but it should work.

Comment: I thought about it, and it probably works too, but for some reason it doesn't really smell right..I mean what if the client will send some string that may crash the server? you really trusting the client here, which is not a good thing to do :)

Comment: @Israelg99 How can it crash the server? But to be sure, you validate the string is letters only, then prefix the string with your package name, and assuming package only contain all the fighter classes, you are now safe.

Comment: @Israelg99 Then restrict what `String` the client can send. I have no idea how your program works, but doesn't that answer your question "How to instantiate a class from a String"?